# Node.js 10000 concurrent HTTP requests every 10 seconds

Tags: node.js, http, concurrency, polling, long-polling

I have a use case where I need to make more than 10,000 external HTTP requests(to one API) in an infinite loop every 10 seconds. This API takes anywhere from 200-800ms to respond.

**Goals**:

1. Call an external API more than 10,000 times in 10 seconds
2. Have a failproof polling system that can run for months at a time without failing

**Attempts**:
I have attempted to use the [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachLimit) library and limit requests to 300 concurrent calls(higher numbers fail quickly) but after about 300,000 requests I run into errors where I receive a connection refused(I am calling a local Node server on another port). I am running the local server to mimic the real API because our application has not scaled to more than 10,000 users yet and the external API requires 1 unique user per request. The local response server is a very simple Node server that has one route that waits between 200-800ms to respond.

Am I getting this error because I am calling a server running locally on my machine or is it because Node is having an issue handling this many requests? Any insight into the best way to perform this type of polling would be appreciated.

Edit: My question is about how to create a client that can send more than 10,000 requests in a 10 second interval.

Edit2:
Client:

```
//arr contains 10,000 tokens
const makeRequests = arr => {
  setInterval(() => {
    async.eachLimit(arr, 300, (token, cb) => {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/tokens/${token}`)
        .then(res => {
          //do something
          cb();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          //handle error
          cb();
        })
    })
  }, 10000);
}
```

Dummy Server:

```
const getRandomArbitrary = (min, max) => {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

app.get('/tokens:token', (req, res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.send('OK');
  }, getRandomArbitrary(200, 800))
});
```

Comment: You can try an HTTP load generator? Something like [this](https://github.com/rakyll/hey) one?

Comment: Are you saying that I should use this to see if the issue is my local server?

Comment: Maybe? To be honest I'm not sure entirely what your question is. To me it looks like you're just trying to run a load test experiment, so I figured I'd throw that suggestion out there.

Comment: Is this a question about creating a client that can run that many requests to a server that can easily handle everything a client can send at it or a question about creating a server that can handle that many requests?  And, if it's about creating a client, it seems like you're already saying that the server involved here has a problem with as many requests as you're trying to do so that would be a target server limitation.  I'm very confused about what problem needs to be solved here.

Comment: I updated the post, but I am trying to create the client that is sending a minimum of 10,000 requests every 10 seconds to an external API that I do not own.

Comment: So, you get a "connection refused" error when attempting to run your client code against a local dummy server.  That sounds like your dummy local server can't handle this many simultaneous connections.  Or the system you're running both of these on doesn't have enough resources to be running this many connections at once.  It is not clear at all if this is a system configuration/resource issue or a coding issue.  You don't show us anything about either so not much for us to go on here.

Comment: That is correct. My dummy server is literally just an express server that has 1 route and returns after waiting 200-800ms, and my request server is just looping over an array with 10,000 elements using the Async eachLimit method and limiting the number of concurrent calls to 300. I can attach a code example

Comment: Well, first order of business is to figure out if it's the client or dummy server that is causing the problem.  When the  client starts getting connection refused, can any other client successfully connect to the server (you could write a 10 line test app to verify)?  If not, then the problem is apparently in your dummy server.  If so, then I'd start looking at resource usage in the client.  What platform are you running this one?

Comment: I added some code snippets, and I am running on a 2.6ghz i7 Quad Core MBP. Node is taking up a minimal amount of resources(< 30% CPU usage).